# Imagemagick Thumbs and Php

Tags: php, imagemagick, jpegoptim

I have 2 types of thumbnails. I use Imagemagick.

[Small Thumbnail](https://cdn.pornstarlab.com/thumbs/5/a/7/3/3/5a6c31a8bb0d07.18686028.mp4/5a6c31a8bb0d07.18686028.mp4-8.jpg)

[Video Poster Thumbnail](https://cdn.pornstarlab.com/thumbs/5/a/7/3/3/5a6c31a8bb0d07.18686028.mp4/5a6c31a8bb0d07.18686028.mp4-8b.jpg) called "b" images.

The width and height is 278x170 for small thumbnails but I cropped them 208x128 to get rid off watermarks and I do.

I have my php files [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m73Hn.jpg) and [rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoDT6.jpg)

I pointed the place where "b" images have been but I don't know how to edit these codes to crop that "b"images same as small thumbnails to crop watermarks by not decreasing the quality of picture of "b".